# How do I connect to sample databases og SQl Server 2008, while using visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2008

How can i connect to the sample databases of sqlserver 2008.. I have installed Visualstudio 2010 and  sqlserver  express edition that comes with Visual studio 2010..
SQL-Server-2008-things that are are installed in my PC are
Sql server Configuration tools that include
1)SQL Configuration Manager
2)sql server error and usage reporting..

i dont have any enterprise manager installed..do i have to install it?

do i have to install the sample database separatly

I am a beginner please some body help me  at this :(

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, open your project and then click "Data" on the menu bar.  Select "Show Data Sources".  This will open the Data Sources window.  Click the "Add New Data Source" link at the bottom of the Data Sources window to start the Data Source Configuration wizard. 
On the first screen of the wizard, select "Database".  On the second screen select "Dataset".  On the next, you'll want to click the "New Connection..." button - this will bring up the Add Connection dialogue box.  Change the data source to "Microsoft SQL Server Database File" and then browse to the database file you're going to use.  You'll also need to set how the application is going to log on to SQL Server - with Windows authentication (Windows username/password) or SQL Server Authentication (SQL Server username/password).  Before clicking "OK" on the Add Connection dialogue box, make sure you click "Test Connection" to make sure that everything is working. Once you've tested successfully, click "OK", make sure your new connection is selected in the dropdown and then click "Finish".  Your new data source should show up in the Data Sources window.